# How to programmatically halt execution in Vimscript?

Tags: exception, vim

I'm trying to catch an exception in Vimscript and halt execution in the function where error occurs.  I can catch the error fine, but the function where it happens is several levels down in the call stack so all that happens is another error occurs in the calling function.  The error message I put in the 'catch' of the original function never gets seen, and regular Vim error is generated in a calling function.  I can put try/catches in all the way up the chain, but it seems like I should be able to stop execution right where it happens.

Here's an example to illustrate what I mean:

```
function Function1()
     call Function2()
endfunction

function Function2()
     call Function3()
endfunction

function Function3()
    try
       [...]
    catch
       echo "An error occurred.  Execution should be stopped . . ."
       " I've tried putting 'normal <ctrl-C>' but it doesn't seem to 
       " do anything. . .  Execution silently goes back to function2, 
       " where another (uncaught) error occurs
    endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: How about returning a suitable error indication and bailing out?

Comment: That was first thought, but the function with error is called from multiple functions in code so it would require changing code in a lot of different spots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to abort execution if there is an error in some function, but also show custom error message instead of default one. In this case you should use `throw`, try replacing `:echo` in the `:catch` block with it. You can also use the following hack in order to both keep vim error message and show your one:

```
function Function3()
    try
        [...]
        let succeeded=1
    finally
        if !exists('succeeded')
            echo "An error occurred.  Execution should be stopped . . ."
        endif
    endtry
endfunction
```

By the way, correct syntax for using special keys in `:normal` is `:execute "normal! \<C-c>"`, not `:normal! <Ctrl-c>`.

Comment: Zyx -- Thanks, will try but I don't think it will work.  The calling function depends on a return value, so if Function3() fails it's sure to generate an error in calling function, which will overwrite any echo command.  Could fix the calling function itself, but Function3 is in fact called from multiple spots in the code, seems like unnecessary work to go through code putting in extra code wherever Function3 gets called.  Not a huge deal, I was just trying to generate friendlier and less intrusive error message, which I thought would be simple, but maybe not. . . .

Comment: ZyX -- Another thing, seems to be no way to have echo text viewable at same time as a regular Vim error message.  The error message is ended with a 'Press <ENTER> or enter command to continue...' message in the command line.  My echo statements are getting executed, the output is just getting overwritten.

Comment: @HerbertSitz If Function3 fails in this case it throws an exception which is not to be catched in any other level. If you replace `echo` with `throw` in your example exception will be yours, if you use my code snippet it would keep error generated by vim and transformed into exception. I use exceptions almost only for fatal failures, so I have a bunch of throws and almost no `catch` blocks, and I assumed you wanted the same.

Comment: @HerbertSitz Use `throw`. `Press <ENTER> or enter command to continue` has nothing to do with vim errors, it just means that there are enough messages to require this prompt. You can disable this completely with some option (I don't remember which exactly) (maybe it is also causing vim to display press-enter prompt on any error, I do not really know). Replacing `:echo` with `:echom` also makes sense, and you can try surrounding `echom` with `echohl ErrorMsg` at the start and `echohl NONE` at the end too.

Comment: @HerbertSitz But yes, you can't break execution of all underlying functions without generating a bunch of messages like `missing endif` that can hardly considered to be friendly. `echo` statement works for me both with `finally` and with `throw` inside `catch`.

Comment: ZyX: Thanks for all your help.  Got it working with your basic framework and using 'echoerr' instead of plain 'echo'.  May check 'errorformat' option to see if I can suppress or reformat some of the main error message, but it's good now.  Thanks again.

Comment: @HerbertSitz Never use `:echoerr`. You will be surprised because of things like «I have put call to a function with echoerr inside a :try block and now nothing works». You should use either `:echomsg` (possibly with surrounding `:echohl`) or `:throw`, `:echoerr` will bring you pain when you will try to debug errors like I mentioned.